# How to send email with symfony2 over gmail?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to send an email using symfony with gmail. I mean both the sender and the receiver use gmail.
I configured the config.yml as follows :

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    encryption: ssl
    auth_mode:  login
    host:      smtp.gmail.com
    username:  username
    password:  pass
    spool:     { type: memory }






 $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Hello Email')
            ->setFrom('sender@gmail.com')
            ->setTo('destination@gmail.com')
            ->setBody('hello')
```

Is this code correct?

An other note: 
when I added this code it worked

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new xxxType(), array('key' => 'var'));
```

but with this it does not

```
$form = $this->createForm(new xxxType(),$entity);
```

Comment: I used actually the same account for sender and receiver but I did not receive anything

Comment: Using the same account for sender and receiver may not work with gmail - it tends to filter out messages from yourself (although a search may turn it up). It would be best to create a separate gmail account for serving the messages. In any case you wouldn't want a genuine gmail account password in plain text in that config file.

Comment: I don't know symfony2 but for me looks like you create the message but you don't send it so i think you need to do something like $message.send()

Comment: NB I found the best way to see if message has been sent: look at the sent messages on the gmail account configured to send the mail.

Comment: I get this error: 500 Internal Server Error - Swift_TransportException

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [spool](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html), which delays the sending of emails till you actually send the emails through the app/console command. The mails are kept in memory till then, as outlined in the docs linked before.

In order to send the email, you should stop using the spool, or send them manually.

Comment: I commented the line spool:{ type: memory }  500 Internal Server but I get the following error : Error - Swift_TransportException @Ethena

Comment: What does the exception say? Without some details it's hard to tell what is going wrong and what you should change... Please update your post with what you did and what the result is.

Comment: this is the message displayed after submitting the form =>   500 Internal Server Error - Swift_TransportException @Ethena

Answer (score 0):

I look at the documentation you just forgot

```
 $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/email/email.html